(env) in shell prompt gone because of PROMPT_COMMAND in .bash_profile
PROMPT_COMMAND=__prompt_command
__prompt_command() {
    PS1='\[\e[0;32m\][\u] \[\e[0;34m\]\w/ '
    if git branch 2> /dev/null > /dev/null; then
        PS1+="\[\e[0;33m\]($(parse_git_branch)) "
    fi
    PS1+='\[\e[01;34m\]$ \[\e[0m\]'
}

parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | grep -E "\*" | sed -E "s/\* (.*)/\1/g"
}

I have this script in my .bash_profile. However, when I run source env/bin/activate, the (env) to the left of the prompt is no longer there. I suspect it has to do with the PROMPT_COMMAND hook. How can I fix this?

Rather than invoking git branch in PROMPT_COMMAND to set PS1, you can put the code directly in PS1.   Then virtualenv's prefix in PS1 will not be overwritten.

If you look at env/bin/activate, you'll see it directly adds the name of the virtual environment to PS1, assuming that nothing will ever modify it. Your PROMPT_COMMAND completely overwrites that value, and needs to be responsible for adding the virtual environment name back on each update.
Luckily, activate also exports VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT, which you can use to do just that.
PROMPT_COMMAND=__prompt_command
__prompt_command() {
    PS1=${VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT}
    PS1+='\[\e[0;32m\][\u] \[\e[0;34m\]\w/ '
    if git branch 2> /dev/null > /dev/null; then
        PS1+="\[\e[0;33m\]($(parse_git_branch)) "
    fi
    PS1+='\[\e[01;34m\]$ \[\e[0m\]'
}

parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | grep -E "\*" | sed -E "s/\* (.*)/\1/g"
}


You can append to the already existed PROMPT_COMMAND instead of overwriting it:
PROMPT_COMMAND=(__prompt_command "${PROMPT_COMMAND[@]}")

Take a look at this post.

Does the activate script create a prior PROMPT_COMMAND, as opposed to just setting PS1 as a one-time operation, to make this relevant? AFAICT this answer is predicated on facts which @chepner's answer explicitly states are false: if as chepner says activate directly sets PS1, then there's no prior PROMPT_COMMAND, so this answer won't fix the issue.
